# @section syntax instead of requirejs or browserify for angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, typescript, loader

I understand that [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) and [browserify](http://browserify.org/) can load my files dependent on its current context, and that it is amazing. I would really prefer to use the `@section sections` syntax that the razor engine uses. Was just wondering if there is a way to implement this into a typescript / angularjs application.

for example

**index.html**

```
 @renderSection scripts; 
 // which could turn into something like
 <script data-render="scripts"></scripts>
 // the app.run() could declare all the scripts that will be needed on every        
 // page view
```

**view.html**

```
<script ng-section-repeat="injected in injection"></script> 
// the ng-section-repeat is basically taking all the items in the 
// typescript constructor and then finding out which ones are needed for
// that view.
```

I like the idea injecting application file dependencies in the view , without a configuration file and all the added extras that comes with the loaders.

I just want to easily define what files are needed in the actual view and get them loaded, with angular's dependency injection handling the dependency itself.

If you are handling all your dependencies with `$inject` then , as far as i can tell, dependency is technically already setup in the controllers, all one would need, is to load this as it is called. Which could even eliminate the need for the `@section scripts` completely

**Update**:
What i have done to *sort of* replicate the module loaders is to just use [gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) and define the file order in my `gulp.config.js` and then pass it to the `gulp-src` before running `$.concat` .this allows me to have the files in the gulp steam , in dependent order . They are however loaded on the first load. With [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) the files are tiny ( its now at 566Kb with 16 external libraries loading in 69ms . To put that into perspective it takes 209ms to load one google font ).

I dont know maybe i am not understanding browserify correctly but i honestly struggle to see the need for it, its seems extremely convoluted for something so simple

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using external modules and an injector to do what you asked for:

> I just want to easily define what files are needed in the actual view

```
import {UserFactory} from 'models/userFactory';
import {UserValidator} from 'models/userValidator';
import {Inject} from 'angular2/di';
```

> and get them loaded, with angular's dependency injection handling the dependency itself.

Note: My example uses angular 2.x because I less familiar with angular 1.x and I'm sure you can do something really similar...

```
class SomeComponent {

  userName: string;
  userRating: number;
  rating: number;

  constructor(
    @Inject(UserFactory) UserFactory
    @Inject(UserValidator) UserValidator
  ) 
  {
    this.UserFactory = UserFactory;
    this.UserValidator = UserValidator;
  }
}
```

Then you can use Browserify to create a `bundle.js` file that can be executed in a web browser.

Comment: by "actual view" i mean the `.html` file. I am already using $inject ( for angular1> ) . I dont want to use browserify. Technically i could use wiredep with gulp-concat to organize my initial dependencies and then gulp-uglify to minimize it for production.